# Hough transform and OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, hough-transform

I'm trying to implement Hough transform for circles in OpenCL, but i've encountered really weird problem. Every time i run the Hough kernel, i end up with slightly different accumulator, even though parameters are the same and accumulator is always a freshly zero'ed table (ex. https://i.stack.imgur.com/utA15.jpg). My kernel code is as below:

```
#define BLOCK_LEN 256

__kernel void HoughCirclesKernel(
    __global int* A,
    __global int* imgData,
    __global int* _width,
    __global int* _height,
    __global int* r
)
{
    __local int imgBuff[BLOCK_LEN];

    int localThreadIndex = get_local_id(0); //threadIdx.x
    int globalThreadIndex = get_local_id(0) + get_group_id(0) * BLOCK_LEN; //threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * Block_Len
    int width = *_width; int height = *_height;
    int radius = *r;

    A[globalThreadIndex] = 0;
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(globalThreadIndex < width*height)
    {
        imgBuff[localThreadIndex] = imgData[globalThreadIndex]; 
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if(imgBuff[localThreadIndex] > 0) 
        {
            float s1, c1;
            for(int i = 0; i<180; i++)
            {
                s1 = sincos(i, &c1);
                int centerX = globalThreadIndex % width + radius * c1;
                int centerY = ((globalThreadIndex - centerX) / height) + radius * s1;

                if(centerX < width && centerY < height)
                    atomic_inc(A + centerX + centerY * width);
            }
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

Could this be the fault of how I am incrementing the accumulator?

Comment: Please post a runnable example reproducing your error. My attempt at writing one runs normally and produces the same result every time, but, of course, something can be happening in the part you don't show us. By the way, you can just pass `height`, `width` and `r` as scalars, no need to use 1-element arrays.

Comment: P.S. If it is possible, test your program on another device. Also, [here's an attempt at reproduction](https://gist.github.com/fjarri/aee7b1d3a24bcf20e7e1) using Python with `numpy`, `matplotlib` and `pyopencl`.

Comment: I've uploaded whole solution here http://speedy.sh/m5ZXn/Hough.7z
It seems wierd because my other project which is Irregular Hough transform seems to be working just fine, and circles is based on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have VS to compile it, but the program looks fine. Maybe someone with Windows can help more. Things to try: run on a different device; try to run my code (above). To check for compiler/driver problems: pass scalars as scalars and not arrays; fill `A` with zeros beforehand and not in the kernel; remove local memory usage (you don't need it here); parallelize over accumulator cells, not image pixels (no need for `atomic_inc` this way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem by finding and correcting three issues.

First of all the kernel code, the line:

```
int centerY = ((globalThreadIndex - centerX) / height) + radius * s1;
```

should be:

```
int centerY = (globalThreadIndex / width) + radius * s1;
```

The main change here was dividing by width, not height. This caused inaccuracy problems.

```
if(centerX < width && centerY < height)
```

The above condition was changed to:

```
if(x < width && x >= 0)
    if(y < height && y >=0)
```

As for the accumulator problem, first I will post the code I used to create clBuffer (I am using [OpenCL.net library](https://openclnet.codeplex.com/) for C#):

```
int[] a = new int[width*height]; //image size
ErrorCode error;
Mem cl_accumulator = (Mem)Cl.CreateBuffer(cl_context, MemFlags.ReadWrite, (IntPtr)(a.Length * sizeof(int)), out error);
CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateBuffer");
```

The fix here was simple and pretty much self-explainatory:

```
int[] a = Enumerable.Repeat(0, width * height).ToArray();
ErrorCode error;
GCHandle accHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr accPtr = accHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Mem cl_accumulator = (Mem)Cl.CreateBuffer(cl_context, MemFlags.ReadWrite | MemFlags.CopyHostPtr, (IntPtr)(a.Length * sizeof(int)), accPtr, out error);
CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateBuffer");
```

I filled the accumulator table with zeros and then copied it to device buffer each time I executed the kernel.

The above errors caused the accumulator to look different and bit malformed each time I executed the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(globalThreadIndex < width*height)
{
        imgBuff[localThreadIndex] = imgData[globalThreadIndex]; 
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        ...
}
```

this is undefined behaviour since there is a barrier inside a branch.

All streaming units in a compute unit must enter same memory fence.

Try this:

```
if(globalThreadIndex < width*height)
{
            imgBuff[localThreadIndex] = imgData[globalThreadIndex]; 

            ...
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

Alse there could be another issue if you are using multiple devices:

```
get_local_id(0) + get_group_id(0)
```

here get_group_id(0) is getting group id per device and it starts from 0 for all devices just as get_global_id starts zero too; so you should add proper offsets in the "ndrange" instruction when using multiple devices. Even though different devices can support same floatig point accuracy requirements, one of them may give better accuracy than other and can give slightly different results. If it is single device, then you should try lowering gpu frequencies as it may have defects or side effects of an overclock.